# Cant Upload, Update, Install Plugins After cloning wordpress with backupbuddy

Tags: wordpress, permissions

I've just migrated a client site to her production server using the latest version of BackupBuddy v3.0.40, and at first glance everything looks dandy, but on closer inspection, most WP file functions are borked: update wp, upload images, upload plugin.

I've done this a ton of times (several times on this host), and don't know why its not working here

- I suspect it has to do with the tmp directory, but i can't see a problem..
- another possibility is that a script (installatron via cpanel maybe interfering.. i notice that there are upload folders created for all months up to 2016! i read about this being a solution to permissions issues in WP's past)

This is what I've tried:

- changing the wp-media upload location to the default, changing the 'store in year/month' setting and general wiggling. this was imported as '/home/###/public_html/wp-content/uploads' which looks correct, but unnecessary, the default is wp-content/uploads. neither work.
- changing the permissions on wp-content and uploads dir to 777 (not all contents)
- adding a line to wp-config.php:
  define('WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/'); no dice
- uninstalled all traces of the installatron scripted wp installation (no files or db remain)
- repeating the migration (same backup file, identical results)

confirming that:

- i can create new posts, just not upload media
- it works on the staging server (same host)
- safe mode is off
- apache is running as user, tx suPHP
- the files were extracted by php via the browser
- i've compared phpinfo to other working sites and dont notice anything out of the ordinary

hope you can shed some light!

thanks, Tim

image upload error:

```
“envelope-9887.jpg” has failed to upload due to an error
The uploaded file could not be moved to /home/###/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2012/07.
```

wordpress update error:

```
Download failed.: Destination directory for file streaming does not exist or is not writable.
```

plugin install error:

```
Download failed. Destination directory for file streaming does not exist or is not writable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found, eventually, that I'd overlook the line

```
define('WP_TEMP_DIR', 'old-hard-link-here');
```

which I believe was nestled directly under the wp salts, camoflaged to the tired eye!  Simply removing that line and setting the media path to the default fixed the issue.

I believe that that line was installed by the cPanel script 'Installatron'.
Case closed

Answer (score 1):

sometimes when migrating you may have to look through the database options table and change a few entires, ie:

from the old site structure it could be: /home/yoursiteid/public_html/wp-content/ etc..
but on the new server the structure could have changed?
ie: /home/differentuserid/wwwroot/wp-content/

edit a file on the server to include :

```
echo getcwd() . "\n";
```

just to see if the home directory is the same as your current server or if its changed from your old sevrer, have a check in your database options table and update the entires which ref the old dir structure..

Comment: thanks @Marty - handy line - I've added this to my phpinfo debugging file :)